# preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 1 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

preg_match():Compilation failed in my code.

Preg match expression in my controller is

```
   'phoneno' => 'required|regex:/(+92)[0-9]{10}/',
```

Please tell me what is wrong with the regex.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `+` character. You want to match on a phone number starting with `+92`. But the `+` character means that it expects *1 or more of the preceding character*. Which in this case you don't want.

So in short, change it to this:

`/(\+92)[0-9]{10}/`